# ReactJS | Component to receive props either as constant or server values with Promises

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, es6-promise, formik

I have made a small reusable component from using `Formik`. It is pretty basic. The library's example would make a good starting point, so I am sharing it below as well as the `URL`:

[Code Sandbox for Formik Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/328038x19q)

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";

function Checkbox(props) {
  return (
    <Field name={props.name}>
      {({ field, form }) => (
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            {...props}
            checked={field.value.includes(props.value)}
            onChange={() => {
              if (field.value.includes(props.value)) {
                const nextValue = field.value.filter(
                  value => value !== props.value
                );
                form.setFieldValue(props.name, nextValue);
              } else {
                const nextValue = field.value.concat(props.value);
                form.setFieldValue(props.name, nextValue);
              }
            }}
          />
          {props.value}
        </label>
      )}
    </Field>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        roles: ["admin"]
      }}
      onSubmit={values => alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))}
    >
      {formik => (
        <div>
          <div>
            <Checkbox name="roles" value="admin" />
            <Checkbox name="roles" value="customer" />
          </div>
          <button onClick={formik.submitForm}>submit</button>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(formik.values, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I am passing instead of hardcoded values a prop of Checkbox, which has the the of Strings (Using `PropTypes`). This placeholder props is then populating by values that I pass it depending on the usage from a `Constants.js` file like so.

```
const NameForCheckbox = {
  Name1: 'Value1',
  Name2: 'Value2',
  Name3: 'Value3',
};

export default NameForCheckbox; // Tha is working just fine.
```

**The Problem:**
We might in the future get this info from the `Server Payload`. This will render my approach obsolete, so in order to future proof it, I want to make it render either my data if no server data exist, or bypass them if there are server values.

Now, I was reading up on how to do it and I found Promises able to solve my problem. I tried various things that I won't list here, as I found out by other answers in Stack Overflow not to be correct. I would appreciate if you could help me out here.

MY SETUP:
Until now, I did this, which could be totally not usable, but I will list it.

I create 3 Actions, using redux(`GetDataAttempt, GetDataSucces, GetDatFailure`). Which in return make a `GET` request to that specific endpoint. That will, in turn, use some RxJS functions like so

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { observableFromHttpPromise, combineAndIsolateEpics } from 'utilities/epicsUtil';
import { Type, Actions } from '../actions';

const getDataEpic = (action$, store, deps) =>
  action$.ofType(Type.GET_DATA_ATTEMPT).pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      observableFromHttpPromise(deps.getData()).pipe(
        map(result => Actions.getDataSuccess(result && result.data)),
        catchError(error => of(Actions.getDataFailure(error && error.message)))
      )
    )
  );

const getAllEpics = combineAndIsolateEpics(getDataEpic);

export default getAllEpics;
```

Finally the reducers will either send the payload to the component, which I read with `MapStateToProps` or an empty string.

Now to the tricky part and the reason I asked. **How to make this conditional logic apply to the components using Promises**. **Or anything else.**

Comment: Are you using any redux middleware and are you willing to do so? This can be achieved by using redux-observable or redux-saga

Comment: I am using redux-observable.I am more familiar with Sagas to tell you the truth but in this Projects we use Observables. Our Stack is React/Redux/RxJS with Redux Observables and Seamless Immutable to ensure State Immutability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand how promises change much here.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to display static content in `NameForCheckbox` unless some server information exists. Obviously fetching this information is asynchronous.

The simplest possible implementation would be to dispatch your API request (probably via an action) when the component mounts. In the meantime, you can display the values in `NameForCheckbox` using some simple conditional logic to display either the API data if it exists, or the checkbox otherwise.

```
import NameForCheckbox from './NameForCheckbox';

class Checkboxes extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // dispatch async action here that will eventually populate the
    // apiData prop below
  }

  renderCheckboxes = data => {
    // insert rendering logic here
  }

  render() {
    const { apiData } = this.props;
    const data = someData || NameForCheckbox;

    return this.renderCheckboxes(data);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  apiData: state.reducer.data || null;
})
```

Notice how `data` falls through to the default data when apiData is falsy (which both `null` or `''`, like you suggested, are), but when the data from the API exists in state, it will render that instead.

It's also pretty common to set a loading animation while you wait for the data to return, so you can also start with an initial state of `loading = true`, then set `loading = false` when the API action successfully completes.

```
// In reducer
const initialState = {
  loading: true,
  apiData: null
}

// In component
render() {
  const { apiData, loading } = this.props;

  if (loading) return <Loading />;

  return this.renderCheckboxes(apiData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will do this for now as I need to create multiple instances of this for many components, but Redux Observable needs some more thought and reading for long term solution as I am already using it.... Thanks!!!